# Using Oracle Warehouse Builder With More Recent Version of Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

The documentation for Oracle Warehouse Builder 11.1 indicates it can work with Oracle 11.1 and earlier.  However, we are dealing with multiple databases and one of them is Oracle 11.2 - and we are unable to upgrade our Oracle 11.1 database (which is the one with OWB 11.1).

Is anyone aware of some kind of workaround that would allow us to use OWB 11.1 with Oracle 11.2?

Comment: Have you tried using OWB with your 11gR2 instance?  What happens?

Comment: for various reasons, we are unable to use the 11gR2 instance be the source for our OWB instance.  But it looks like we found a solution.  Will share below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Our DBA discovered that if the database link to our 11gR2 instance was created outside of OWB and then imported into OWB, instead of having OWB create the initial database link, then the 11gR1 version of OWB was able to read our release 2 database.

Answer (score 0):

According to [the OTN Homepage for OWB](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/warehouse/overview/introduction/index.html):

> "OWB 11gR2 is pre-installed with Oracle Database 11gR2, and can be
>   installed and used alongside Oracle Database 10gR2 and 11gR1."

So perhaps the solution you want is to make the 11gR2 database your OWB repository.